# wxwidget 2.9.1 compiling at visual c++, error MSB 3073: The command xcopy

Tags: visual-c++, compiler-errors, wxwidgets

Hallo, 
Im trying to compile wxwidget 2.9.1 in Visual c++ 2010, every time i try there appear this error:

C:\Program Files\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(103,5): error MSB3073: The Command "xcopy ....\include\wx\msw\setup.h ....\lib\vc_dll\mswu\wx\ /Y
22>C:\Program Files\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(103,5): error MSB3073: :VCEnd" ended with code 4.

Is there anyone who can help me out, t tried many things but no chance, at the wiki widgets there is a tip how to do, but it doesnt work at all. Im very pleasureful if someone can help me out.Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The build is trying to copy the file setup.h to a different directory.  Specifically from folder \include\wx\msw\setup.h to \lib\vc_dll\mswu\wx.  Try doing this manually, and solve any problems that arise.

Comment: Hallo, thanks alot for your answer. Now i have an other problem

Comment: Hallo, thanks alot for your answer. Now i have an other problem, i get many warnings like these:  C:\Program Files\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Microsoft.CppBuild.targets(1151,5): warning MSB8012: TargetPath(C:\wxWidgets-2.9.1\build\wx291_msw_vc10\..\..\lib\vc_lib\wxregex.lib) does not match
the Linker's OutputFile property value (C:\wxWidgets-2.9.1\lib\vc_lib\wxregexud.lib).This may cause your project to
build incorrectly. To correct this, please make sure that $(OutDir),
$(TargetName) and $(TargetExt) property values match the value specified in %(Link.OutputFile). How i solve this problem

Comment: Please ask a new question with this problem, rather than trying to squeeze it into a comment.